# Controller to match root routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to have a controller active at the root of my application, so:

www.example.com/1 would return
the post with an ID of 1 in the foo controller.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
get '/:id', :controller => 'foo', :action => 'show'
```

seems to work. Is this the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

in your config/routes.rb file, put:

```
root "TheControllerName.TheMethodName"
```

Older Rails versions may need:

```
root :to => "TheControllerName.TheMethodName"
```

Answer (score 0):

For rails 3 add this to your routes.rb.

```
get '/:id' => 'foo#show', :as => 'show'
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html